# WebStorm and IntelliJ - Search Everywhere (double press Shift) doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Up until an hour ago Search Everywhere (double <kbd>Shift</kbd>) stopped working for both WebStorm and IntelliJ. I've tried invalidating the caches and restarting in both, and repairing the IDE but the problem persists.

Sticky keys is disabled. Same for filter keys and toggle keys.

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is working fine when typing. In other apps it detects whenever I press it.

I've updated both apps to the latest version. Plugins are also updated. I doubt it is plugins as I don't use the same plugins in WebStorm and IntelliJ.

What is causing this?

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the IDE logs right after your press Shift twice? (Help | Show Log in... | open idea.log file and scroll till the end)

Comment: @EgorKlepikov No nothing gets added when I press it.

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for help